# how to call a method in a controller from the view and then iterate the values returned from the method in the same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scenario where i am calling a Controller method from the view,that returns an array of pages,which can be either nil or must be having values.i need to iterate that array in a for loop to generate a dynamic list in my view.pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing logic in your controllers is generally not a good idea you should [move logic into the corresponding model](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/7-move-model-logic-into-the-model).

But if you really want to you can use `controller` variable to reach the actual controller from your view.

Example:

```
<p>
Now we're printing out the result of the some_method:
<%= controller.some_method.inspect %>
</p>
```

Iterating through the returned value is easy:

```
<ul>
<% controller.some_method.each do |item| -%>
  <li>item.inspect</li>
<% end -%>
</ul>
```

Probably the visibility of the method in your controller is not public, so you may need to use the [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) method.

```
<%= controller.send(:my_protected_method).inspect %>
```

#### Update

To handle the `nil` reponse, I would create a helper method in the `ApplicationHelper` class:

```
def my_method
  (controller.my_method || [])
end
```

And then in the view:

```
<% my_method.each do |item| -%>
  <%= item.inspect %>
<% end %->
```

Comment: it should work in both scenarios.(nil and values).if nil i am getting error as..ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for "End of function":String): when i use <% controller.some_method.each do |item| -%> in my view

Comment: That's not `nil` in that case but a string w/ value `End of function`